# is there is a tool to convert pub files to html ( email friendly ) ?

Tags: email, html, web

I have ms publisher file ( newsletters) that consist of five pages .. what is the best way to convert it to html so i can send it to users thought email without any problem

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Office do you use? The best solution is to use the built in Save As target of a webpage. This is available on versions of Publisher since Office 2003.

You might have to tweak which works best in your setup. Single file web pages might not work for all mail clients. Web Page should work, but you'll have to ensure you attach all the relevant images and flatten the directory structure (hand edit the HTML file) too.

[image: Choose save as, then single file webpage]

Answer (score 1):

Unless Publisher is designed to output HTML email, it will be hard to get it there. HTML for email requires a very particular way of coding. Even if you find a way to get it to HTML, it will still require a lot of rework to get it ready for emailing without any problems across multiple email clients.

If you want it to match your Publisher design (depending on how complex it is), you'll have to hire a designer who specializes in email. Otherwise you can try and fit it into a Campaign Monitor or MailChimp template yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention which version of Office/Publisher you are using, but if your not bound to the .html format, then another option is to use the built in "Save for a Commercial Printer" option to export as a .pdf file which anyone can open as Adobe Reader is a free application. Here is a link for Microsoft Office support documentation about this procedure for Publisher for Office 365, Publisher 2019, Publisher 2016, Publisher 2013 and Publisher 2010

[Use the Pack and Go Wizard to save a file for commercial printing](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-pack-and-go-wizard-to-save-a-file-for-commercial-printing-61ae18ff-6659-42b1-9af7-48563142749c)